# Which of these phrases is better : "point out to a" vs "point out a"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one of the above phrases is better suited generally and to the given examples? I'm leaning towards "point out to a" but I don't want to complicate the sentence if it is not necessary

*Example 1: She pointed out (to) a box.*

*Example 2: It doesn't point out (to) a particular place.*

Please suggest if some other words are better suited to the examples. I know some such as *refer to* are better

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I would recommend taking a look at [the English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), it is an excellent resource.

Comment: Regarding the edits: I rejecting the edit removing the 'and' between 'generally' and 'to the given' because I wanted to know which one was generally better suited and which one was better suited for the given examples

Comment: I understand, perhaps an emphasis would make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

In your  example there must be no preposition 'to' because 'to point out' is a transitive verb and it is followed by the direct object only. 'To' is used with the indirect object.
Compare two examples from Oxford Dictionary:
'One would be hard pressed to point out a single fat man among these thousands.’
and:
‘God doesn't extend a hand from the sky and point them out to you.’

Comment: The phrase I wanted was "She pointed out to a box". Does the same rule apply for such a phrase and could you also add your sources?

Comment: There's an example from Reverso.Context.net :     Statements were made by the representatives of India and Egypt who pointed out to corrections to be made to the draft resolution.

Comment: Could you add the link to the same? Thank you very much in advance